# How come my window.open() with _parent does not work in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, window.open

I've created a button and on click it should open a popup to google.com. If you test the JSFiddle in Chrome you'll see that it works but in IE it does not...

How come this doesn't work in IE but in Chrome it does?

```
<input type="button" value="Print Timetable" class="printButton cap_button hubActionButton" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com', ' _parent','height=550, width=800');"/>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vyLwu/4/

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying " _parent" for the second parameter, but that isn't a valid option. Did you mean to use "_parent"? See w3 documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: For anyone else confused, there is a space before Daniel's first " _parent" and not the second